# scp command behaves differently when used with expect utility

Tags: shell, quoting, wildcards, expect

```
expect -c 'spawn scp -C -o CompressionLevel=9 ~/partFiles/* abc@10.200.4.15:/export/home/abc/; sleep 10; expect password; send "secretPassword\n";interact'
```

throws - `~/partFiles/*: No such file or directory`

Just

`scp -C -o CompressionLevel=9 ~/partFiles/* abc@10.200.4.15:/export/home/abc/`

however, works perfectly.

Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `~` and `*` are expanded by the shell, but I bet expect invokes `scp` directly, bypassing the shell so those don't get expanded.  You could try spawning `sh -c` the `scp` command.

If it's an option, it might also just be easier to share your key with the server though so you don't need expect for this at all.

Using the `sh` technique the command will end up looking like:

```
expect -c 'spawn sh -c "scp -C -o CompressionLevel=9 ~/partFiles/* abc@10.200.4.15:/export/home/abc/"; sleep 10; expect password; send "secretPassword\n";interact'
```

Comment: I didn't get it. What did you mean by `You could try spawning sh -c the scp command`. I am a little new to all this. Would you kindly explain?

Comment: Sure, I was just thinking that instead of using expect to spawn scp directly, which skips the filesystem expansion you want, you could spawn a shell to run the scp command in like: `expect -c 'spawn sh -c "scp -C -o ..."'` so you have a shell that will invoke your scp command and expand `~` and `*` for you

Comment: You have quotes around the password, which close the quotes for the `sh -c`  You'll need to escape those to use this solution

Comment: Actually, I think the problem now is that the OP needs `"` after `/export/home/rgh/`; i.e., at the end of the `scp` command.

Comment: Did't work. I tried ` expect -c 'spawn sh -c "scp -C -o CompressionLevel=9 ~/partFiles/* abc@10.200.4.15:/export/home/rgh/; sleep 10; expect password; send \"password\n\";interact"'`

Comment: @G-Man is right, you want the `sh -c` to only be quoting the scp command itself, the rest are `expect` commands, not `sh` ones

Comment: I just updated my answer with that command line too, glad it worked, and thanks again to @G-Man for that last push for the quoting help

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. The correct command should be: ` expect -c 'spawn sh -c "scp -C -o CompressionLevel=9 ~/partFiles/* abc@10.200.4.15:/export/home/abc/"; sleep 10; expect password; send "passowrd\n";interact'`

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to Eric's good answer: Tcl can do glob expansion

```
expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    set timeout -1      # use this instead of sleep
    set files [glob -nocomplain ~/partFiles/*]
    if {[llength $files]} {
        spawn scp -C -o CompressionLevel=9 {*}$files abc@10.200.4.15:/export/home/abc/
        expect password
        send "secretPassword\r"
        expect eof
    }
END_EXPECT
```